# Using from {x}.field in DSL in Drools

Tags: dsl, drools

I have the following Drools DSL "sentence":

```
[when]The field {field} in the module {module} contains value {value}=$a : {module} ( {field} != null)
      String( this.equalsIgnoreCase("{value}") ) from $a.{field}
```

where the `field` is a `Set` of Strings.

Now, if I have two of these rules, it obviously won't work as the variable `$a` occurs twice. So I wanted to improve the rule to make the variable, well, variable:

```
[when]The field {field} in the module {module} contains value {value} as {a}={a} : {module} ( {field} != null)
      String( this.equalsIgnoreCase("{value}") ) from {a}.{field}
```

This doesn't work, I can't use the part `{a}.`, that breaks.

So, my questions are: Is there either a way to rewrite the rules or a way to allow the `{variable}.` notation to work? Alternatively, is there a `contains` operator which works case insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I subscribed to the Drools-Users mailing list, I got an answer:

http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Using-from-x-field-in-DSL-tt4017872.html

Summary: Bug in DSL parser, as a workaround add an extra letter after the variable on the RHS: `... as {a}={a}x (...) ... from {a}x.{field}`